# translation issue in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, internationalization, react-i18next

Hi I am reading value of `translation` from `database`. they are stored like `key value` like below.

```
"marketing_contact":"Contact",
"marketing_address":"Address",
"marketing_phone":"+00 00 00 00 00",
```

to use them I am using i18-next library and reading the value like below.
`i18n.t("marketing_contact")` . it is working properly.

but I need to put these inside the form. at every place other than form it is working.

```
 const inputForm = [
 {
  "canHaveAnswer":true,
  "contact":i18n.t("marketing_contact"),
  "address":i18n.t("marketing_address")
 }
 ];
```

suppose if I write `"contact":"Shruti",` inside the `form` then it works but it is not replacing value of `i18` inside it.
I am not sure what wrong I am doing?
Other than this form wherever I have used these `i18n.t("marketing_contact")` they are working.

Comment: What value _are_ you getting?

Comment: the value inside the t..means it is displaying key instead of value

Comment: Have you run `init` before making the call? What do you get if you run `i18n.exists` on those values?